# Cannot read property 'menu_id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, relationship

I tried to create database with 3 tables: `restaurant`,`restaurant_menu`,`menu` and their relationship is restaurant have many menu and menu can belong to many restarant by sequelize in Nodejs.

## restaurant.model.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const restaurant = sequelize.define('restaurant', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        address: DataTypes.STRING,
        phone: DataTypes.STRING,
        lat: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        lng: {
            type: DataTypes.DOUBLE,
            allowNull: false,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        user_owner: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            defaultValue: 0
        },
        image: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        },
        payment_url: {
            type: DataTypes.TEXT,
            allowNull: false
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
    restaurant.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        restaurant.belongsToMany(models.menu, {
            through: {
              model: models.restaurant_menu
            },
            foreignKey: 'restaurant_id'
        })
    };
    return restaurant;
};
```

## menu.model.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const menu = sequelize.define('menu', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false
        },
        name: DataTypes.STRING(50),
        description: DataTypes.STRING(500),
        image: DataTypes.TEXT
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
    menu.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
        menu.belongsToMany(models.restaurant, {
            through: {
                model: models.restaurant_menu
            },
            foreignKey: "menu_id"
        });
    };
    return menu;
};
```

## restaurant_menu.model.js

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const restarant_menu = sequelize.define('restarant_menu', {
        restaurant_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'restaurant'
            }
        },
        menu_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            allowNull: false,
            references: {
                model: 'menu'
            }
        }
    }, {
        freezeTableName: true,
        timestamps: false
    });
    restarant_menu.associate = function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
    };
    return restarant_menu;
};
```

i tried to run migration, but i get error:

```
Cannot read property 'menu_id' of undefined
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are writing old syntax, checkout documentation.

https://sequelize.org/master/manual/advanced-many-to-many.html